# TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have this code :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math

x = np.linspace(-3,3,100)
y = math.sin(x**2) + 1.1 - ((math.e)**-x)

plt.plot(x,y,label='y = x**2')

plt.title('sin(x^2) + 1.1 - e^-x')

plt.xlabel('x axis')
plt.ylabel('y axis')

plt.grid(alpha=.4,linestyle='--')

plt.show()
```

and I get this error:

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Can someone help me in finding what the problem is?

Comment: `math.sin()` doesn't know how to deal with a numpy array. Use `np.sin(x**2)` instead of `math`

Comment: `math.sin()` expects a single value and you are passing a matrix. You probably wanna use np.sin()

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you're trying to apply Python operations (specifically, `math.sin`) to an array, namely a NumPy array of type `np.ndarray`.  NumPy actually has a workaround for this by implementing functions that apply the same fundamental operations **element-wise**, i.e. you'll want to replace the line:

```
y = math.sin(x**2) + 1.1 - ((math.e)**-x)
```

With the following:

```
y = np.sin(x**2) + 1.1 - (np.exp(-x))
```

That fixed the issue you were facing.

In general, when working with `numpy`, you'll want to carry out these kinds of substitutions.  However, it is important to note that `numpy` can apply [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) rules (i.e. understand how to apply scalar operations to `np.ndarray` objects in an element-wise fashion) to the following operations:

- `+` (addition)
- `-` (subtraction)
- `*` (multiplication)
- `/` (division)
- `//` (integer division)
- `**` (exponentiate)

Comment: `x**2` is fine.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'll update this answer!